# Version(s) of JDK that can be used with particular Android API levels

Tags: java, android

I have developed my own Java JAR (using JDK 1.6 compatibility) and I'm trying to use it in my Android app (with `android:minSdkVersion="16"`)
All works fine except some (old) Android versions have a (more than one) method missing. In particular, I tried to use (in my JAR library):

```
String languageTag = "en";
locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(languageTag);
```

but this throws `NoSuchMethodError` on devices running API below level 21.

Now I can avoid this dependency by using:

```
locale = new Locale(languageTag);
```

which does work in API 16 and up, but I expect there are many more dependencies like this, where a JDK method is missing in particular Android level(s).

Is there a list somewhere of which JDK 1.6 methods are/aren't supported by the various API levels?
Better, is there a tool (cf lint) which would examine my JAR and report any usage outside a particular Android API range?

Answer (score 1):

JDK is irrelevant here and this is completely unrelated.

Locale's `forLanguageTag()` is clearly [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag(java.lang.String)) as `added in API level 21` therefore it's matter of your code that tries to use the call not checking the API version it runs on. You need fix your library and do some checks prior calling methods that may may not be available on certain versions of the framework using [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)[BUILD.SDK_INT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT), so in this case

```
if (BUILD.SDK_INT >= BUILD.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // ok to use forLanguageTag()
} else {
   // no luck. do the alternative approach
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not pollute my JAR with android-specific tests.

But what I'm really after is a tool that will look for such dependencies and warn me. I don't want to have to check every JDK 1.6 library method for Android support every time I code such a call, just like my IDE checks for JDK 1.6 support.